# Refactorizaciones TypeScript

Tags: angular

Buen día/noche, estoy haciendo un programa web en Angular y lo que pasa es que hace mucho no lo tocaba, desde la versión CLI 10, tengo un problema con una refactorizaciones hacia un query. Este es el pedazo de código que no termina de cuadrar:

```
private getCharactersQuery(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.query = params['q'];
      this.getDataFromService();
    });
  }
```

El error me lo marca VSCode en la parte de `"(params: ParamMap)"` y en la parte de `"params ['q']"`
.Cabe resaltar que ya tengo importado el modulo ParaMap, (`import {ParamMap} from '@angular/router';`)
el error dice "Ninguna sobrecarga coinside con esta llamada"

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La nueva forma es usando `queryParamMap` y usando el método `get` para obtener un valor:

```
route.queryParamMap
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      params.get('key');
    });
```